# DOMpdf. File writes to server but file itself is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

Hi amazing slack community.

Im using dompdf 0.8.0 to manage some pdf magic on my Woocommerce site. 
Ive created a function that streams a PDF invoice on click to the browser and this works really well.

My next task is to attach a PDF invoice to the order email and Ive got this pretty much nailed to. However, the file that is created doesnt contain any content.

My file/folder permissions are set correctly 755/644 and even setting a 777 folder in the doc root didnt solve any permissions issue.

Ive found a few threads but nothing seems to match or resolve my issue.

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
$dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$dompdf->load_html($content);
$dompdf->render();
$uploadspath = wp_upload_dir();     
$upload = file_put_contents($uploadspath['basedir'].'/'.$filename, $content);
```

The path Im trying to write to is this (dumped from $uploadspath['basedir'].'/'.$filename)
/var/www/designcuts/wp-content/uploads/1524762.pdf

Comment: What is `$output` supposed to be? That is what you are writing to the file, but you have not shown us where you would fill that variable in the first place.

Comment: Ah you've helped me realise Im a total idiot. Thank you. However, now the file is being written and the file now has a size Im getting the following error. File type HTML document (text/html) is not supported

Comment: When I open the file in a text editor all I get is the HTML. No pdf has been rendered.

Comment: You need to catch what the `render` method would otherwise output directly to the browser. Check https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#php-example-with-ob_start for an example how to do that using PHP output buffering.